# How to use to_csv function save dataframe including semicolon " or without semicolon \

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I want to save dataframe from excel to .h file including semicolon  "

Below is my code.

```
def remark_to_device(row):
            if row['Remark'] == 'used':
                return f'{row["device name"]}'
            else:
                return 'FFFFFFF'
        result = '\n'.join(df_Project_Change_Battery_paramer.apply(remark_to_device, axis=1).tolist())
        result_list = result.strip().split('\n')
        df_result  = pd.DataFrame(result_list, columns=['device name'])
        df_result['device name'] = '"' + df_result['device name'] + '",'
        print(df_result)
```

below is my df_result

```
   device name

0  "AP22A8N",
1  "AP22ABN",
2  "AP19B5L",
3  "AP20CBL",
4  "AP18C8K",
5  "FFFFFFF",
```

```
    df_result.to_csv(r'../INC/OPDATABASE.H', na_rep='NA', columns=['device name'], header=None, index=None, mode='a', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar='\\', doublequote=False, line_terminator='\n', sep=',')
```

But the data in OPDATABASE.H shows as below.

```
"AP22A8N"\,
"AP22ABN"\,
"AP19B5L"\,
"AP20CBL"\,
"AP18C8K"\,
"FFFFFFF"\,
```

How can I remove the semicolon, or use other methods to save file as below?

```
"AP22A8N",
"AP22ABN",
"AP19B5L",
"AP20CBL",
"AP18C8K",
"FFFFFFF",
```

Since there is already a lot of data on it that needs to be kept, it cannot be overwritten.

Comment: It's called a backslash. A semi-colon is `;`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with the following, notice I removed `escapechar='\\'`:

```
df_result.to_csv(
  r'../INC/OPDATABASE.H',
  na_rep='NA',
  columns=['device name'],
  header=None,
  index=None,
  mode='a',
  quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL,  # quotes everything regardless of the field type [1]
  doublequote=False,
  line_terminator=',\n',
  sep=',')
```

[1] [thepythonguru: csv files](https://thepythonguru.com/python-how-to-read-and-write-csv-files/)